# Extract "Hover" information from icon while in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, hover, icons, system-tray

When you hover over an icon in the system tray, it displays a message. I was wondering if that information can be retrieved / extracted while in a batch file.

Comment: Not without third party utilities.

Comment: Squashman, what utilities would those be?

Answer (score 0):

Although this doesn't work with the 'system tray/notification area' it is an example batch file leveraging powershell which answers the title question.

```bat
@Echo Off
If /I Not "%~x1"==".lnk" Exit/B
Set "myLnk=%~1"
For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In (`
    Powershell -C "&{$sh = New-Object -COM WScript.Shell;"^
    "$desc = $sh.CreateShortcut('%myLnk%').Description;$desc}"
`) Do Echo="%%~A"
Timeout -1
```

It should output a shortcut's, `hover display text` by simply dragging and dropping one onto the script.